# How to limit lines in scid vs pc in annotate mode?

Tags: analysis, scid

I would like to reduce the number of lines calculated by the engine to speed up the analysis but I cannot find the appropriate option for that. Does anybody know how to do this in Scid vs PC?

Answer (score 2):

In Scid vs PC, after you turn on an engine, a window with analysis opens. In that window you can see icons like **Stop Engine**, **Add Move**, **Add Variation** etc. (see picture below).

Among them, there is a small box with a number (marked by a red circle in the picture below), namely the number of lines suggested by the engine. Adjust that according to your preference. If I understood your question correctly, that should solve your problem. Just for the sake of completeness, I have the version  4.13 of Scid vs PC.

[image]

Comment: It is good suggestion but it works in current session what if I want to set it for next/all session. After I will hit annotate again it become 4 lines again after I set it to one before also?

Comment: @Chameleon I tried looking at the file **options.dat** in my scidvspc directory. In that file, you can find values for many different variables that Scid vs PC uses. Unfortunately, I cannot find the variable that controls the number of lines of analysis, and I do not see another easy way of setting this number to some fixed value.

Comment: @Zvonimir, there is a file called engines.dat

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for is variations. To save this for future use, make a new analysis engine.

Under Tools, click either Analysis Engine or Analysis Engine #2:

[image: Tools dropdown menu]

Click New...:

[image: Analysis Engine List]

Fill in the fields and hit Configure UCI engine:

[image: Configure Scid engine]

Now you can set the Multiple variations variable to any amount of 'lines' you want:

[image: Configure UCI engine]

Don't forget to look at all the other nifty variables you come across :-)

This sets the same number as [Zvonimir indicated in their answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/13804/19803), but now it can be saved as a standard setting. If you want to use it again, just select the correct engine.